# Custom layout UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, layout, infinite-loop, uitableview

So I just tried subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and aligning the labels the way I want by overriding `-layoutSubviews`.

When I call `super` and change a label's `frame`, however, the app appears to be stuck in an infinite `-layoutSubviews` loop.

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 40.0);
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I ended up subclassing from UIView and adding these labels myself.

Comment: Ok. I take it you don't get header reuse from the table view then? I got it to work by not using the built-in labels and added my own, that way you can still reuse the headers. Took a while to get it working though.

Comment: I have them cached anyway to do some nice animations when the screen rotates, so I wouldn't want to reuse them anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems an attempt to modify the frame of `backgroundView` or `contentView` not only causes an infinite loop, it will ignore any values you set to their frames, rendering their existence fairly useless. I've reverted to using the `backgroundView` and `contentView` as dumb containers for my own custom subviews with their own background visuals and layout properties. :S